# Bootstrap alert not showing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display this alert on my html page but the background color of the alert is not appearing. I've included the following bootstrap files (bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap.min.js) and (jquery-2.0.3.js). Any idea what I am missing here? Thanks

```
 <div class="alert">
            <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
            <strong>Accounts Expiring Soon</strong>
        </div>
```

I am using Bootstrap 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .alert-class itself does not contain a definition for the background color. You need to add another class to determine which kind of alert you want to use, e.g.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">...</div>
```

Check the [Bootstrap page](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts) for more info on the alerts.